# Collatz Conjecture c++ weird output with big numbers

Tags: c++, output, long-integer, collatz

So, I was bored, and decided to make something completely random, then I came across the collatz conjecture: start with any positive number, and if it is even, devide by two. If it is odd, multiply by three and add one. When repeating this, you will end at the number one. So I made this code:

//Collatz Conjecture by Lucas Knook

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << setw(5) << n;

    while(true){
        if(n % 2 == 0 && n != 1){
            //is even
            cout << " E" << endl;
            n /=2;
            cout << setw(5) << n;
        }
        else if(n != 1){
            //is odd
            cout << " O" << endl;
            n = n * 3 + 1;
            cout << setw(5) << n;
        }
        else break;
    }
    cout << " O" << endl << endl << "end loop";
    return 0;
}
```

I am still learning c++ (I just completed the sololearn course, and I am about to get the "C++ for dummies all-in-one" book), but I think this is a good start for me, and it works.

There is just one little problem: If I use big numbers, it does stop at one, and gets the odd and even right, but...

Look at this first part of the output when entering 
"`1000000000000000000000000`" :

```
9223372036854775807 O
9223372036854775806 E
4611686018427387903 O
-4611686018427387906 E
-2305843009213693953 O
-6917529027641081858 E
-3458764513820540929 O
8070450532247928830 E
4035225266123964415 O
-6341068275337658370 E
-3170534137668829185 O
8935141660703064062 E
4467570830351532031 O
-5044031582654955522 E
-2522015791327477761 O
-7566047373982433282 E
-3783023686991216641 O
7097673012735901694 E
3548836506367950847 O
-7800234554605699074 E
```

Ehm, that's a bit weird, isn't it? (don't look at the line breaks, it is perfectly stacked, it just doesn't show here, because I copied the output)

Can someone please explain me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I think you have exceeded the maximum value for a 64 bit integer.

Comment: yeah, I thought so too, any way to make it bigger? xD

Comment: You need a big int library.

Comment: Or if you are sat down bored, write your own big int functionality as an excercise? It can be quite easy to do if you use base 32bit and 64bit operations, though it is easier to understand and debug if you use base 8bit and 16bit operations

Answer (score 1):

You've exceeded the limits of `long long` integer values. The first value in your output is truncated to be much smaller than your input, then when you get to `4611686018427387903` it's multiplied by 3, since it isn't even. That's when it overflows the type and wraps around into negative values. You'll need to use a BigInteger library, like [TTMath](https://www.ttmath.org/).

Comment: Am I doing anything wrong? it doesn't give any errors, but when I start it, it stops immediately:

Comment: #include <iomanip>
    #include <ttmath/ttmath.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        ttmath::Int<1> n;
        cin >> n;
        cout << setw(5) << n;

Comment: @LucasKnook Please post your new code as a separate question. It's not easy to help debug via comments. (And you'll get a lot more people looking at it.)

Answer (score -1):

Basically as other people pointed out you don't check for overflow. But I would like to point out different thing, your code is still not valid as you don't check if you got into endless loop, when multiplication and division sequence generates the same numbers, your while will never end.

This is correct code with simple overflow detection:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

bool colatazConjecture(int n) {
    std::unordered_set<int> localComputed;
    int newN = 0;

    while (n != 1) {
        if (!localComputed.emplace(n).second) {
            throw "Cycle detected";
        }

        newN = n;
        if (n & 0x1) {
            newN = 3*n + 1;
            if (newN <= n) {
                throw std::overflow_error("Overflow for " + std::to_string(newN));
            }
        } else {
            newN >>= 1;
        }
        n = newN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Collatz Conjecture is a very simple math problem, no one know why it always ends with one, I only check if it reached the number one yet, it will not go on forever, it will always stop at 1.

Comment: No, thats why it is called "conjecture", you have to check if on your way you are not computing the same numbers over and over again.

Comment: Added code for your reference, if you don't know what I'm talking about, your snippet is incorrect. If you downvoted please revert.